# Postgres return optional table sets using if statement in a function

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to build a function something like follows (highly simplified)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tester(boo boolean)
RETURNS TABLE (
    foo int
)

AS $$
BEGIN
IF boo is false THEN 
with t as (select 10);
return t
ELSE 
with t as (select 20);
return (select * from t)
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

is it possible to do something like this?  I want to return different table sets depending on a boolean condition...

Answer (score 0):

If the schemas of the queries differ, you can use a function that returns a `SETOF record`. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE elbattrue
             (nmuloc1 integer,
              nmuloc2 text);

CREATE TABLE elbatfalse
             (nmuloc1 text,
              nmuloc2 numeric);

CREATE FUNCTION noitcnuf
                (retemarap boolean)
RETURNS SETOF record
AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF retemarap THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT *
                        FROM elbattrue;
  ELSE
    RETURN QUERY SELECT *
                        FROM elbatfalse;
  END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But then you have to specify the schema of the returned set when `SELECT`ing from the function. Like

```
SELECT *
       FROM noitcnuf(true) elbattrue(nmuloc1 integer,
                                     nmuloc2 text);
```

or

```
SELECT *
       FROM noitcnuf(false) elbatfalse(nmuloc1 text,
                                       nmuloc2 numeric);
```

(The names don't need to match though. The important things are the data types.)
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=f4df813837fce2118def4741b401123f)

If the schemas do not differ, you can go straight forward.

```
CREATE TABLE elbattrue
             (nmuloc1 integer,
              nmuloc2 text);

CREATE TABLE elbatfalse
             (nmuloc1 integer,
              nmuloc2 text);

CREATE FUNCTION noitcnuf
                (retemarap boolean)
RETURNS TABLE (LIKE elbattrue)
AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF retemarap THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT *
                        FROM elbattrue;
  ELSE
    RETURN QUERY SELECT *
                        FROM elbatfalse;
  END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The calls then do not need to specify the schema:

```
SELECT *
       FROM noitcnuf(true);
```

and

```
SELECT *
       FROM noitcnuf(false);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=ec2059177c52a00767aacc34031a8598)